# If water vapor changes its phase, how is it possible to maintain specific volume?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, gas, volume

I was doing my thermal engineering exercises when I encountered a problem. The problem specified a fixed and rigid container with a volume $V=0.17\ m^3$, as I have a $T-S$ diagram for water, they give me the pressure initially and the temperature.
It undergoes a process in which its tempreature drops due only by heat exchange to the surroundings to a $T=90^{\circ} C$.

Now, the only way I could match the solutions to an approach was to consider the specific volume constant in my diagram.

But, as it changes from vapor to water, and the water doesn't fill the space as vapor (or as i get it, any gas) does, how is it possible to maintain the same specific volume?

It may be trivial, but I'm a bit confused.
Thank you!!

Comment: the weighted average of the liquid specific volume and the vapor specific volume remains constant

Comment: In addition to the other comments, as the temperature decreases, the pressure decreases.  If any water condenses, the specific volume of the vapor phase changes because there are less moles (or kg) of water vapor in the given volume.

Answer (score 0):

The specific volume of the mixture of vapor and liquid is the same since the volume and mass of the total contents is fixed.

But as the vapor changes to liquid the specific volume of the vapor phase of the mixture drops while the specific volume of the liquid phase of the mixture increases. At any given time the fraction of the mixture that is in the vapor phase is called the quality of the mixture.

If you take the product of the specific volume of the vapor and the mass of the vapor and add that to the product of the specific volume of the liquid and the mass of the liquid, you get the total volume. Then of course if you divide the total volume by the total mass you get the specific volume of the mixture.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! However, how could be demonstrated that the specific volumes of both balance each other out?

Comment: @ManuVS See update to my answer.